# Google analytics api get schema csv for custom data source

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using Google Analytics API and I want to get through the API the schema csv header for a Custom Data Source.
I am using the list method for Custom Data Sources as it is the single endpoint available: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/customDataSources/list

This returns the list of Custom Data Sources but it doesn't return the schema field for the list of items.
In the list of fields for a Custom Data Source the schema field exists: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/customDataSources

Is there any parameter that needs to be added to the request to also get the schema field?